# cakephp ajax updated div wont appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

i want to create an basic web app that submits inputed data to database and also updates the div to show the data saved to database without reloading the whole page using ajax pls help me im stuck with this thnks..

h**ere is my messages/index.ctp**

```
<div ="success"> </div>
<?php
echo $this->Html->script('jquery', FALSE); 

echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('message');
echo $this->Js->submit('Send',array('update' => '#success'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>

<div id="sending" style="display:none; background-color:lightgreen"> </div>
```

**and my MessagesController.php**

```
<?php

class MessagesController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Js');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index()
    {
        if(!empty ($this->data))
        {
            if($this->Message->save($this->data))
            {
                if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
                    $this->render('view', ajax);
                else
                {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Message Sent!');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function view()
    {   
            $this->loadModel('Message');
            $data = $this->Message->find('all');
            $this->set('dbdata',$data);

    }
}
```

**my messages/view.ctp**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Message</td>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($dbdata as $name) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name['Message']['name'] ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $name['Message']['email'] ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $name['Message']['message'] ?> </td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What version of cake are you using?

Comment: `<div ="success">` ???

Comment: sorry for late reply its cakephp ver 2.7.7 and sorry ive changed it to <div id="success"> but still my div content wont update btw thanks for the reply